# South not migrating taggit.managers

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-south, django-taggit

I just added `tags=TaggableManager()` in my models.py file. And i initiated to run `python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial` it shows below error

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/schemamigration.py", line 151, in handle
    for action_name, params in change_source.get_changes():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/south/creator/changes.py", line 460, in get_changes
    model_defs = freeze_apps([self.migrations.app_label()])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/south/creator/freezer.py", line 32, in freeze_apps
    frozen_models.update(model_dependencies(model))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/south/creator/freezer.py", line 96, in model_dependencies
    depends.update(field_dependencies(field, checked_models))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/south/creator/freezer.py", line 132, in field_dependencies
    value = get_attribute(field, attrname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/south/utils/__init__.py", line 38, in get_attribute
    value = getattr(value, part)
AttributeError: 'TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'primary_key'
```

In south migration tutorials itself they said to add below two lines. I did

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_ignored_fields
add_ignored_fields(["^taggit\.managers"])
```

Nothing happened. But the same error coming again